# Tensorflow Deprecation Warning

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow

I am trying to create a convolutional neural network for image classification using one of the open access github codes. I have two classes of images. But, when I start running the one part of the code I keep getting this error

```
/Users/user/anaconda/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ipykernel/__main__.py:46: DeprecationWarning: elementwise == comparison failed; this will raise an error in the future.
```

This is the part of code that has error (although the origin of this error are probably somewhere else, my intuition tells me that it lies in the labelling of images, but I am not sure how to fix that, I tried relabelling multiple times, nothing worked to fix this).

```
def print_test_accuracy(show_example_errors=False,
                    show_confusion_matrix=False):

    # Number of images in the test-set.
    num_test = len(test_images)

    # Allocate an array for the predicted classes which
    # will be calculated in batches and filled into this array.
    cls_pred = np.zeros(shape=num_test, dtype=np.int)

    # Now calculate the predicted classes for the batches.
    # We will just iterate through all the batches.
    # There might be a more clever and Pythonic way of doing this.

    # The starting index for the next batch is denoted i.
    i = 0

    while i < num_test:
        # The ending index for the next batch is denoted j.
        j = min(i + test_batch_size, num_test)

        # Get the images from the test-set between index i and j.
        images = test_images[i:j, :]

        # Get the associated labels.
        labels = test_labels[i:j, :]

        # Create a feed-dict with these images and labels.
        feed_dict = {x: images,
                 y_true: labels}

        # Calculate the predicted class using TensorFlow.
        cls_pred[i:j] = session.run(y_pred_cls, feed_dict=feed_dict)

        # Set the start-index for the next batch to the
        # end-index of the current batch.
        i = j

    # Convenience variable for the true class-numbers of the test-set.
    cls_true = test_class_labels

    # Create a boolean array whether each image is correctly classified.
    correct = (cls_true == cls_pred)

    # Calculate the number of correctly classified images.
    # When summing a boolean array, False means 0 and True means 1.
    correct_sum = sum(correct)

    # Classification accuracy is the number of correctly classified
    # images divided by the total number of images in the test-set.
    acc = float(correct_sum) / num_test

    # Print the accuracy.
    msg = "Accuracy on Test-Set: {0:.1%} ({1} / {2})"
    print(msg.format(acc, correct_sum, num_test))

   # Plot some examples of mis-classifications, if desired.
    if show_example_errors:
        print("Example errors:")
        plot_example_errors(cls_pred=cls_pred, correct=correct)

   # Plot the confusion matrix, if desired.
    if show_confusion_matrix:
        print("Confusion Matrix:")
        plot_confusion_matrix(cls_pred=cls_pred)
```

Comment: From the above code, the only probable source of this warning is `correct = (cls_true == cls_pred)`. Please check if both these arrays have same size

Comment: You might be interested in my article https://martin-thoma.com/image-classification/

Answer (score 0):

Try [`tf.equal`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/control_flow_ops/comparison_operators):

```
correct = tf.equal(cls_pred, cls_true)
```

or, if it is a probability distribution rather than just the argmax already:

```
correct = tf.equal(tf.argmax(cls_pred, 1), tf.argmax(cls_true, 1))
```